# How to make use of a try{}-block-variable in a method?

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

I would like to pass the connection-variable myConn to several other classes. However, when I

```
return myConn;
```

myConn cannot be resolved to a variable. Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javafx.application.Application;

public class MP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz);

        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        Application.launch(MPfxlogin.class, args);      
    }

    public Connection getConn() {

        return myConn;  
    }   
}
```

I have to tried to fix the problem by making the method static and adding a static variable:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javafx.application.Application;

public class MP {

    static Connection myConn;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz);

        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        Application.launch(MPfxlogin.class, args);      
    }

    public static Connection getConn() {

        return myConn;  
    }   
}
```

Now, the program runs, but the static variable remains null, thus remains untouched by

```
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz);
```

The same problems occur when omitting the try-block and working with

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
```

How can I fix this? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Don't do this. Use the application class as entry point of the app and move these kind of initialisations to the `Application.init` method. Avoid using `static` members extendsively. This just encourages you to violate the single reponsibility principle.

Comment: Can you tell me some more on how to use init() in this respect? Thx.

Comment: Take a look at the lifecycle and the method documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `myConn` shadows the static variable `myConn`. So what you are doing is - you are initializing a local variable called `myConn` and not the class variable.

Just remove the part that (re) declares it in `main`.

```
try {
    //Initializes the static variable myConn
    myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I did that... Thx!